# Find the value of $\left\lfloor 1.9 \right\rfloor$. In general, is this operation (floor) 1-to-1? Onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Hi I an studying for the midterm and I would like to know if I got these questions correct.

$\left\lfloor 1.9 \right\rfloor$ - I said that it was an onto function.

2.Find the value of $\left\lceil -1.9 \right\rceil$. In general, is this operation (ceiling) bijective?

$\left\lceil -1.9 \right\rceil$ - I said this one was also an onto function.

Thank you.

Comment: If you say what is considered the codomain, we could answer to this question.

Comment: Check your definitions against the functions.

Comment: The function was $F:$ **R** $ \rightarrow$ **Z**